# Excel Not Filtering Properly

Tags: microsoft-excel, xlsx

I have an issue with a very large excel spread sheet with approximately 152,000 records. I have noted that when I try to filter by any column, the filter will organize it, but not remove extraneous columns. For example, if I am looking to filter by City, and I put "New York," it will indeed organize such that all New York records are on top, but it does *not* hide all other records from the list. Instead, it shows the New York ones on top, and presents all other records just underneath it.

I need the filter to hide all non-New-York records. I have tried clearing the filter and recreating it to no avail. Are there any suggestions here?

Comment: Are you using AutoFilters? Maybe you could add a screenshot of how you apply the filter and of the (wrong) result. This should make it easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: you can upload images to http://imgur.com and link to them here. Someone with enough reputation will likely embed them for you

Comment: It sounds like there is an empty row under New York.